# Approximating a Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: finite-fields

Given the problem of computing the GCD of two given elements over any finite field with characteristic 2.

$$ r_1 = q_1r_2 + r_3 \\
   r_2 = q_2r_3 + r_4 \\
   r_3 = q_3r_4 + r_5 \\
   \vdots \\
   r_{k-1} = q_{k-1}r_{k} + r_{k+1}\\
   r_k = q_kr_{k+1}$$

Exist any way of find the aproximate value of $r_{k+1}$, for $k > 3$ without know the $q_{k-2}$ value?

Comment: Do you mean the gcd of two polynomials? The non-zero elements of a  field, finite or not, are units.

Comment: GCD  = greatest common divisor

Comment: approximate mean any polynomial such that permit advance in the iterative euclidean algorithm and this easiest to calculate than calculate the $r_{k+1}$ normally.

Comment: @juaninf: The same problem as in your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/324298/11619). I'm sorry that I have to put it bluntly. Either you don't understand what a finite field is, or you don't understand what Euclidean algorithm is. If all the elements $r_i,q_i$ are, indeed, elements of a finite field, then $r_3=0$. Always. No exceptions. This is what André is also saying. For your previous question I asked you to write down an example, but you didn't oblige. Care to do it now??!